# What does 'Microsoft Symbol Servers' include?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, debug-symbols

In my list of PDB locations, there is an entry called 'Microsoft Symbol Servers':

[image]

I cant find any information as to what this actually includes. More specifically, are any of my explicitly included symbol servers redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just adds a hard-coded URL to your list.  It is msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.

In other words, you have the URL twice in your list.  You can delete the last one.